# Lit-Element import statement with unpkg

Tags: lit-element, unpkg

I have some projects with Lit-Element and all was fine till today. I had the usual import statement .
`import {LitElement, html,css,} from "https://unpkg.com/lit-element@latest/lit-element.js?module";`
Well I also have the option to install the library via npm but I want it to be the way it was.
Any suggestions what is wrong or how to fix it?
BTW the error in the browser:

Cannot generate module for lit-element@3.0.0-pre.3/lit-element.js

SyntaxError: unknown: Support for the experimental syntax 'nullishCoalescingOperator' isn't currently enabled (14:54):

12 |  * subject to an additional IP rights grant found at
13 |  * http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt

> 14 |  */var s;const i=t;((s=globalThis).litElementVersions??(s.litElementVersions=[])).push("3.0.0-pre.3");class o extends t{constructor(){super(...arguments),this.I={host:this},this.Φo=void 0}createRenderRoot(){var t;const e=super.createRenderRoot();return(t=this.I).renderBefore??(t.renderBefore=e.firstChild),e}update(t){const r=this.render();super.update(t),this.Φo=e(r,this.renderRoot,this.I)}connectedCallback(){super.connectedCallback(),this.Φo?.setConnected(!0)}disconnectedCallback(){super.disconnectedCallback(),this.Φo?.setConnected(!1)}render(){return r}}o.finalized=!0,globalThis.litElementHydrateSupport?.({LitElement:o}),globalThis.litElementPlatformSupport?.({LitElement:o});const l={O:(t,e,r)=>{t.O(e,r)},P:t=>t.P};export{o as LitElement,i as UpdatingElement,l as _Φ};
> |                                                      ^
> 15 |
> 16 |

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator (https://git.io/vb4Se) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

undefined

Comment: This problem should have disappeared by now. It was occurring because the pre-release for the next major of lit-element was published to the latest tag of npm by accident and unpkg currently doesn't support nullish coalescing